# Where I can find the official XSD schema for RSS 2.0

Tags: rss, xsd, schema

I am looking for the XSD schema of RSS. Via Wikipedia I have found several pages on the specifications of RSS 2.0 but none offers an XSD schema. I found several correct xsd files around on the web but all these schemas are created by individual developers. I'm surprised not to find a site official RSS 2.0 specification and provides a formal XSD.

Do you know where I can find a perfect match of the official XSD schema for RSS 2.0?

Comment: XSD isn't popular in many circles - it's commonly accused of being too complex - and it's not necessary in order to process XML, so I don't think it's really a surprise that there isn't a schema for RSS 2.

Comment: @MatthewWilson: criticized in some circles perhaps - loved in others. I promote XSD for the declarative standardization and strictness, which removes the need to implement additional XML validation in code. This standardized strictness leads to fewer errors locally - but especially in communications across systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google "rss 2.0 xsd schema"](https://www.google.com/search?q=rss%202.0%20xsd%20schema) returns a bunch of hits.

I believe there is no one "official" schema, just [the official spec](https://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification) from which various people have developed XSD schema.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps: https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html

"The World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) is an international community that develops open standards to ensure the long-term growth of the Web."